# Is there a good AddIn for Visual Studio that will launch msbuild targets?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, msbuild

One of the things I like about the Java IDEs out there is that they typically have the ability to allow a user to right-click on an Ant file and run one of the targets.

I've got an msbuild file in my solution that is used for migrating the application database, and would kill to be able to right-click on it, select "update" or "rollback" and have it run.

My searching has not turned up anything meant to run inside VS2008, just a shell extension for windows explorer.

Has anybody seen such an animal out there?

Cordially,

Jon

Comment: How to run msbuild from your application ?

http://devintelligence.com/2006/09/how-to-run-msbuild-from-your-application/

Comment: Seems like you could start with the code in the "how to run msbuild from your app" article, along with the VS SDK, and build a VS add-in.

Answer (score 2):

I've develpped this addin:

http://www.netlogics.ch/devcenter/addins.msbuild.html

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know no such addin exists.

But there is the [MSBuild Sidekick](http://www.attrice.info/msbuild/) which is a stand alone app.

Sayed Ibrahim Hashimi

Answer (score 0):

Maybe batch file with msbuild.exe command line will be helpful. Easy to write, easy to debug, runs instantaneously;)